# Handling pyTelegramBotAPI floating keyboard value

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm new on making Telegram chatbot using pyTelegramBotAPI. In this case, i have multiple choices, the 'Trapezoid' and 'Simpson'. Here is the following code

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['calculate'])
def welcome(message):
    print(message)
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('Trapezoid', 'Simpson')
    reply = bot.reply_to(message, "Select computation method" ,reply_markup=markup)
    if(reply.text == 'Trapezoid'):
        bot.register_next_step_handler(reply, trapezoid_handler)
    elif(reply.text == 'Simpson'):
        bot.register_next_step_handler(reply, simpson_handler)

def trapezoid_handler(message):
    bot.send_message(message.id, "Trapezoid Block")

def simpson_handler(message):
    bot.send_message(message.id, "Simpson Block")
```

Here is a picture when i run the /calculate command

[image]

Here is picture when i press the 'Trapezoid' button
[image]

As you can see, when i press the 'Trapezoid' button, the trapezoid_handler was not executed.

The goal is, when i press either 'Trapezoid' or 'Simpson' button, it later move to the following button value. Am i access the floating keyboard value correctly? How do i access the floating keyboard value?

Thank you for your respond

Answer (score 0):

Here, it returns reply text (i.e "Select computation method") So you're not getting actual value when you click buttons.

Fixed Code :

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['caluculate'])
def welcome(message):
    print(message)
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('Trapezoid', 'Simpson')
    reply = bot.reply_to(message, "Select computation method" ,reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(reply, markup_handler)

def markup_handler(message):
    if(message.text == 'Trapezoid'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Trapezoid Block")
    elif(message.text == 'Simpson'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Simpson Block")
```